# Drupal user_save() duplicate email address

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a module where I try to create some users.

```
$newUser = array(
        'name' => "Bob",
        'pass' => "pass",
        'mail' => "a@a.com",
        'status' => 1,
        'init' => "a@a.com"
);
$newUserObject = user_save(null, $newUser1);
```

If a user is all ready created with the same mail address i am not getting *false* returned I get the user object who all ready existed. Is there any way I can be told that the user all ready exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try calling user_load with the email address before trying to create the user, to see if it returns a user object. Here's an example ([borrowed from here](http://www.daveshaw.net/content/how-load-drupal-user-email-username-or-uid)):

```
//search by email
$account = user_load(array('mail' => check_plain($email)));
if ($account->uid) {
  //user found
} else {
  //user NOT found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching for the user before creating the user. Assuming drupal 6:

```
user_search('search', {email}, TRUE);
```

Or just query directly and see if the query returns `FALSE`.

```
db_result(db_query('SELECT name FROM {users} WHERE LOWER(mail) = LOWER('%s'), $email));
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_search/6

Answer (score 0):

To do this in drupal 7 you need to use different function, like this.

```
//search by email
$account = user_load_by_mail(check_plain($old_user['email_address']));
if ($account->uid) {
  //user found
} else {
  //user NOT found
}
```

as [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load_by_mail/7) is the function for D7